# Can smoke be coloured by a UV image?

Tags: particles, smoke-simulation

In blender, I am trying make an object emit smoke in different colours at the same time based on where on the object it is emitting from. Is it in any way possible to use a uv map on an object to control the smoke particles emitting from that object?